# How to view the query cache statistics when using hazelcast as second level cache for hibernate

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hibernate 5.2.12.Final and hazelcast 3.12 for a application. I am running a hazelcast cluster. Also have hazelcast-mancenter-3.12 running to monitor the cluster and it all works great.

However I could not find anyway to see the statistics for the hibernate query cache hits from hazelcast mancenter or any other way.

So whats the best way to find out what are the query cache hits from hibernate when using hazelcast

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast Management Center doesn't gather Hibernate stats. It only collects stats from Hazelcast cluster members. For query cache, Hazelcast Hibernate integration [doesn't distribute data among Hazelcast cluster members](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/#configuring-query-cache-and-other-settings), but keeps the data in its local cache and uses Hazelcast topics to distribute events between members. So, Hazelcast cluster members don't have any data, only the Hibernate integration has in its local cache.

In your case, you can get Hibernate query cache statistics via `SessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics()` programmatically, or via any other standard means that Hibernate provides.